# How to search and remove Redis data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using redis-om npm library to work with Redis and there is a method to remove single key:

```
const {Client, Entity, Schema} = require('redis-om');
....
await this.repository.remove(<key>)
```

but is there a way to remove multiple entries at once like:

```
await this.repository
  .search()
  .where('keyfield')
  .equals(<key>)
  .return.all()
  .remove();
```

or it can be done in For Loop only?

Comment: Is this just a `DEL` or `HDEL`? If so, it does take multiple keys at once as an argument.

Comment: I need to delete whole set of records.. So it's DEL. .but I'd like to do it in batch

Comment: Note that the [`DEL` command](https://redis.io/commands/del/) takes *multiple* keys as arguments. Does the `redis-om` wrapper allow that, too?

Comment: so this is my question if anyone could do it with redis-om

Comment: What does the documentation or source code say?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
const data = await this.repository
  .search()
  .where('keyfield')
  .equals(<key>)
  .return.all()
const entityToRemove = [];
for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
  entityToRemove.push(data[key].entityId);
}
await this.repository.remove(entityToRemove);
```